# Getting first 3 values of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array that looks like this

```
array ([apple] => 1, [dog]=>2, [cat]=>5, [bread]=>9, [shoes]=> 4)
```

Is it possible for me to print the first 3 values of the array? If so, how? Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$firstThreeElements = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
```

Where 0 is your offset and 3 is the number of elements you want.

Comment: @Ben, why not? surely the difficulty he is having is in getting the first three elements of the array not in printing them?

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways.

```
list( $first, $second, $third) = $array;
echo $first . ' ' . $second . ' ' . $third;
```

Or:

```
echo array_shift( $array);
echo array_shift( $array);
echo array_shift( $array);
```

Or:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $array as $el) {
    if( $i >= 3) break;
    echo $el;
    $i++;
}
```

Or:

```
foreach( array_slice( $array, 0, 3) as $el) {
    echo $el;
}
```

Or:

```
echo implode( ' ', array_slice( $array, 0, 3));
```

Comment: no need for manual index count... `foreach( $array as $i=>$el)`

Comment: @Ben - `$i` will contain the key, and this is an associative array.

Comment: A solution using `array_slice` is probably the most compact and future proof. `list` and `array_shift` will get more and more verbose as requirements change, and the `foreach` is always ugly when there's a counter involved.

Answer (score 2):

Using iterators:

```
$array = ['apple' => 1, 'dog' => 2, 'cat' => 5, 'bread' => 9, 'shoes' => 4];

foreach (new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 0, 3) as $key => $val)
{
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```